# Using ARKit to process online video, is it possible?

Tags: arkit

Apple ARKit is awesome, however, it looks like it can only take the device's front/back end camera as the video source. My question is if it is possible to use the online video or some other video stream as the video source of the ARKit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome, I don't think it is possible, because ARKit uses accelerometer, gyroscope to get device position and scan to world. I don't know how it can be possible over the video. Also ARKit basic requirement is access to camera.